# Dell Inspiron 5593: How to install ubuntu with all its drivers properly?

Tags: system-installation

I have a `DELL XPS` system which is very old. Few years back when I installed ubuntu on my system, sound card broke and I could only use earphone to hear videos. As I tried multiple ubuntu installation on a span of few months, I don't remember the exact version of ubuntu which led to sound card breakage.

Now I have a `DELL Inspiron 5593` which runs `Windows 10`. The [dell](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-in/drivers/supportedos/inspiron-15-5593-laptop) site says it supports `Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS` and [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/certified/201907-27237) says

> Pre-installed in some regions with a custom Ubuntu image that takes advantage of the system’s hardware features and may include additional software. Standard images of Ubuntu may not work well, or at all.

I want to dual boot my machine with `Ubuntu 18.04`. How do I make sure my installation will work properly on my machine ? Or Is there a way to download the custom Ubuntu image the site mentions?

Comment: You can install any version of Ubuntu including 18.04, 20.04 and 22.04 if hardware specs are enough (RAM). If you have any problems, you can ask specific questions. There is not general way to "make sure" everything is OK for a specific laptop. But most likely all should work. You can also test it from a LiveUSB before installation.

Comment: But why the ubuntu site says *Standard images of Ubuntu may not work well, or at all*. If I I install and my sound card breaks, I can not get it back.

Comment: You sound device won't "break" anyway. If it doesn't work with some release it can be fixed in many cases, but if it doesn't at all, you can install another release, another kernel or Windows, etc.

Comment: That post about Ubuntu certification is very old. Most likely new releases, or even an updated 18.04.work without any problems.